# Yet Another Uncaught TypeError: : Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am writing a bit of JS code to switch classes for certain DOM elements.
Everything is working as it should, but I am also getting this error and this
prevents the code that follows to be executed.

I added a check to make sure that the array of elements is not empty as I thought
this was the problem. But still the error occurs. Debugging always showed a value for `old_name` when `replace` is called on it. Am I missing something JS-esque?

This is the part of the code that causes the error, specifically line 31:

```
  if (w > MOBILE_THRESHOLD) {
    responsive_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("desktop");
    if (responsive_elements.length > 0) {
      for (i in responsive_elements) {
        var old_name = responsive_elements[i].className;
        var new_name = old_name.replace("desktop", "mobile");
        responsive_elements[i].className = new_name;
      }
    }
```

When necessary I will be happy to provide more code, or whatever information is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Never use `for...in` loops to iterate array-like objects!!!!!**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1529630)

In this case, the `HTMLCollection` has enumerable properties like `item` or `namedItem`. Accessing these won't return an HTML element, so `className` will be undefined.

To iterate properly, you can use one of these

```
for(var i=0; i<responsive_elements.length; ++i) {
  // ...
}
```

```
[].forEach.call(responsive_elements, function(element, index, collection) {
  // ...
});
```