# Use hasAttribute() get TypeError: hasAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I try to find out the number of `<img>` elements that do not have "style" attribute in a **HTML** file by using **JavaScript**.

My solution: find out numbers of `<img>` tags as "**imgCount**", then get number of `<img>` tags with "style" attribute as "**imgStyCount**". After that, use "**imgCount**" minus "**imgStyCount**" to get the final result that I wish to know.

However, something goes wrong. My browser keep told me

> TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...)[K].hasAttribute is not a function

At the if statement.
And the weird thing is, the ***alert(document.getElementsByTagName("img")[k].hasAttribute("style")*** show the if statement result is TRUE.
How it can be like not a function and give the true value?

```js
var imgCount = 0;

var imgStyCount = 0;

var result;

for (k in document.getElementsByTagName("img")) {

  if (document.getElementsByTagName("img")[k].hasAttribute("style") == true) {

    alert(document.getElementsByTagName("img")[k].hasAttribute("style"));

    console.log("    <img> =: ", document.getElementsByTagName("img")[k].style);

    imgStyCount++;

  }

  imgCount++;

}
result = imgCount - imgStyCount;
```

```html
<img height="150px" src="Http://flax.nzdl.org/images/ngf.jpeg" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-right:20px;" />
<img src="Http://flax.nzdl.org/images/abc.jpg" />
<img src="Http://flax.nzdl.org/images/fbc.jpg" />
<img src="Http://flax.nzdl.org/images/agc.jpg" />
<img src="Http://flax.nzdl.org/images/abt.jpg" />
```

Comment: [Never use `for...in` loops to iterate array-like objects!!!!!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36296155/1529630)

Comment: Check what value k has when you get that error. You might be surprised.

Comment: Thanks all of you. I finally realise what's wrong with my crap code.

Comment: Yet another misleading error message. It's like saying Budweiser is not a beer just because you are drinking a can of Coke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use `for-loop` to iterate `image` elements than `for-in`

```js
var imgStyCount = 0;
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var k = 0; k < elems.length; k++) {
  if (elems[k].hasAttribute("style")) {
    imgStyCount++;
  }
}
var result = elems.length - imgStyCount;
alert(result);
```

```html
<img height="150px" src="Http://flax.nzdl.org/images/ngf.jpeg" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-right:20px;" />
<img src="Http://flax.nzdl.org/images/abc.jpg" />
<img src="Http://flax.nzdl.org/images/fbc.jpg" />
<img src="Http://flax.nzdl.org/images/agc.jpg" />
<img src="Http://flax.nzdl.org/images/abt.jpg" />
```

[**Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/jeLfaoau/1/)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple way without using loop.

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

`document.querySelectorAll('img[style]')` will select all the `<img>` elements on the page having `style` attribute.

```js
var result = document.querySelectorAll('img').length - document.querySelectorAll('img[style]').length;

alert(result);
```

```html
<img height="150px" src="Http://flax.nzdl.org/images/ngf.jpeg" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-right:20px;" />
<img src="Http://flax.nzdl.org/images/abc.jpg" />
<img src="Http://flax.nzdl.org/images/fbc.jpg" />
<img src="Http://flax.nzdl.org/images/agc.jpg" />
<img src="Http://flax.nzdl.org/images/abt.jpg" />
```

Comment: that's fantastic, I wish I could come with same idea. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You're welcome.

```
function hasAttr(el, attr) {
      if(typeof el === 'object' && el !== null && 'getAttribute' in el  && el.hasAttribute(attr)) return true
      else return false
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
<span medium-img>Whatever</span>

alert($('span').is('[medium-img]')); // Returns true
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.